# Go to source code using double click in TexStudio

Tags: pdf, texstudio, ubuntu, viewers, forward-inverse-search

I recently moved to Ubuntu and have started using TexStudio as a replacement for TeXnicCenter.

One of the nice features of TeXnicCenter was that we could double click on a pdf, say in Sumatra PDF, and go to the source code.

In TexStudio, I'm using the integrated PDF viewer, where I can do the came thing except that its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click.

Can I somehow get double-click on PDF to get the same behavior? I have tried all options but could not figure out a way.

I want to avoid using SumatraPDF or anything else unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: this is a feature request, which has been made two years ago. it's on the DEV team's list, but at a low priority

Comment: Is it a problem with TexStudio? Maybe I can use another viewer?

Comment: wouldn't say problem, more a missing feature. you could use `evince` as an alternative

Comment: Five years ago I used ubuntu, xubuntu with the precision. I suggest you use this editor that is best for this OS with Acrobat Reader usual. See at the link http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/.

Comment: @naphaneal can you share details of the feature request? Maybe its fixed in a beta version.

Comment: @Sebastiano I'm assuming you are talking about TexMaker. I tried that but had this and another problem, which is why I moved to TexStudio. See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/863072/how-do-i-remap-ctrl-q-and-ctrl-w-to-custom-actions-in-texmaker

Comment: it's this one: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/627/